# Extending default shader in three.js

Tags: three.js

I would like to extend the default lambert material shader of three.js.
I basically would like to add some custom code at the end of the default fragment shader so the last line will apply my color transformations.

It's there any simple way to do that? Or should I rewrite a completely new one adding the default code on it?

Comment: Others have asked that question, and each case is different. Give it a go, and if you have problems, then post your code and ask a specific question about it. Your other option is to create your own `ShaderMaterial`.

Comment: @WestLangley finally I've create as you said a ShaderMaterial using the predefined code from the default shaders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a custom **ShaderMaterial** using the predefined blocks from the default materials.

Comment: Is there any other way to mark it as resolved? not to leave it open forever

Comment: I expect there are others who would love to know how you extended the default Lambert material. Perhaps a simple jsfiddle? If you want, you can delete the question.